# I can't get the right path in XPath

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Does someone knows the right command/path to get the
**ident**, **shortTitle**
And a **string** that begins with a " **/** " (Note that there is a chance that the position of that string changes in certain circumstances)

I have this block of code where I presenting the **string** but then I wouldn't have the **ident** and **shortTitle**

---

```
$result = $xpaths->xpath("//*[ident = '$page']/moduleConfiguration/config//string[starts-with(.,'/')]");
foreach ($result as $item) {

echo item

 };
```

---

*The full path is*

```
/org.olat.course.Structure/rootNode/children/*[type = 'st' or type = 'sp' or type = 'bc']/moduleConfiguration/config/entry/string
```

---

> ```
> ....
> <org.olat.course.nodes.STCourseNode>
>    <ident>81473730700165</ident>
>    <parent class="org.olat.course.nodes.STCourseNode" reference="../../.."/>
>    <type>st</type>
>    <shortTitle>General Information</shortTitle>
>    <longTitle/>
>    <learningObjectives/>
>    <displayOption>content</displayOption>
>
>    <moduleConfiguration>
>       <config>
>          <entry>
>             <string>allowRelativeLinks</string>
>             <string>false</string>
>          </entry>
>          <entry>
>             <string>file</string>
>             <string>/kgalgemeneinformatie.html</string>           <---
>          </entry>
>          <entry>
>             <string>configversion</string>
>             <int>3</int>
>          </entry>
>          <entry>
>             <string>display</string>
>             <string>file</string>
>          </entry>
>       </config>
>    </moduleConfiguration>
>
>  <noAccessExplanation></noAccessExplanation>
>  <preConditionVisibility></preConditionVisibility>
>  <preConditionAccess></preConditionAccess>
>  <scoreCalculator></scoreCalculator>
> </org.olat.course.nodes.STCourseNode>
> ...
> ```

it would be wonderful if this could work in 1 foreach.

Kind regards

Dieter

Comment: How do you need them? Concatenated to a single string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting them as nodes in one loop, you'll have to group them together with the '|' identifier:

```
//*[ident = '$page']/moduleConfiguration/config//string[starts-with(.,'/')]|//*[ident = '$page']/shortTitle|//*[ident = '$page']/ident
```

Or you could group them all in one node with the concatenate function:

```
concat(//*[ident = '$page']/moduleConfiguration/config//string[starts-with(.,'/')], //*[ident = '$page']/shortTitle, //*[ident = '$page']/ident)
```